# TFS ServiceEndpoint Issue

Tags: tfs

I'm having troubles trying to add Azure Resource Manager Service Endpoint in TFS 2017. When i enter the required data and click on "Verify Connection" I can see the verified

[image]

when I click OK button , I get the following error

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is there any error message in IIS logs?

Comment: Nothing in the logs

Answer (score 0):

First double check if you have followed below tutorials to create this service Endpoint:

- [How to Setup an Azure Resource Manager Endpoint](https://github.com/geeklearningio/gl-vsts-tasks-azure/wiki/How-to-Setup-an-Azure-Resource-Manager-Endpoint)
- [Creating an Azure Resource Manager Service Endpoint](http://donovanbrown.com/post/Creating-an-Azure-Resource-Manager-Service-Endpoint)

Such as make sure  you have gave the service principal access to create resources in your subscription.

> 1. Click Browse and select Subscriptions
> 2. Select the subscription you are using
> 3. Click the Access button
> 4. Click Add
> 5. Select Contributor as the roll
> 6. Search and select the name of the application you just created
> 7. Click OK to grant the service principal access to your subscription

For more troubleshooting, please take a look at this link-- [How to: Troubleshoot Azure Resource Manager service endpoints](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/azure-rm-endpoint)

---

*Update from OP*

Issue fixed by Upgrade to *TFS2017 update1*.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. we did upgrade yesterday to TFS 2017 update 1 and issue was fixed , i was able to create endpoint services no issues.